# Code-first approach vs. database-first approach, how is all the heavy work in SQL replaced in code-first?

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I have a fairly good experience in EF code first, I like the concept of dealing with tables like classes. Now I switched to DB-first as it is my current company's approach to deal with database.

There are always issues in updating model from database in the edmx file, not like migration where all updates were easy as executing a single command, as well not splitting work between Visual Studio and SSMS. I want to discuss using EF code-first with my team leader, I know he doesn't know it well because they didn't use it, but they rely heavily on stored procedures, views, user-defined functions .. etc.

I'm wondering, where all this heavy work in SQL can be replaced when using code first. Are all these can be replaced by using just methods? Isn't using the SQL features have better performance than code-first when they are queried from the server?

Really, if Microsoft encourages using EF code-first, what would the database-centric features future be?

Comment: In the end it is SQL that is executed against the database! Have a look at EF Reverse POCO template, it allows you to map functions, views and UDFs!

Comment: There are some pros and cons to both approaches, but an important argument is that edmx and visual design tool are discontinued in EF7  (.NET Core) and will be deprecated at some point in the not-so-far future. If you want to keep using edmx you will have to use some third-party wrapper that will add an edmx layer over the underlying `DbContext` and Code First Core code. See [this post](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/designer-support-for-ef-core-via-devart/) from Julie Lerman for an example.